# Creating sequence number in hive or Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

I'm facing a data transformation issue :
I have the table here under with 3 columns : client, event, timestamp.
And I basically want to assign a sequence number to all events for a given client based on timestamp, which is basically the "Sequence" columns I added hereunder.

```
Client  Event   TimeStamp                Sequence
C1      Ph      2014-01-30 12:15:23      1
C1      Me      2014-01-31 15:11:34      2
C1      Me      2014-01-31 17:16:05      3

C2      Me      2014-02-01 09:22:52      1
C2      Ph      2014-02-01 17:22:52      2
```

I can't figure out how to create this sequence number in hive or Pig. Would you have any clue ?

Thanks in advance !

Guillaume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the records in a bag (by say grouping all), sort the tuples inside bag by TimeStamp field and then use [Enumerate](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.1.0/datafu/pig/bags/Enumerate.html) function.

Something like below (I did not execute the code, so you might need to clean it up a bit):

```
// assuming input contains 3 columns - client, event, timestamp
input2 = GROUP input all;
input3 = FOREACH input2
         {
             sorted = ORDER input BY timestamp;
             sorted2 = Enumerate(sorted);
             GENERATE FLATTEN(sorted2);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

We eventually modified enumerate source the following way and it works great :

```
public void accumulate(Tuple arg0) throws IOException {
nevents=13;
i=nevents+1;
DataBag inputBag = (DataBag)arg0.get(0);
  Tuple t2 = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple();
for (Tuple t : inputBag) {
  Tuple t1 = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(t.getAll());
  tampon=t1.get(2).toString();
  if (tampon.equals("NA souscription Credit Conso")) {
    if (i <= nevents) {
      outputBag.add(t2);
      t2=TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple();
     }
    i=0;
    t2.append(t1.get(0).toString());
    t2.append(t1.get(1).toString());
    t2.append(t1.get(2).toString());
    i++;
   }
   else if (i < nevents) {
    t2.append(tampon);
    i++;
   }
   else if (i == nevents) {
    t2.append(tampon);
    outputBag.add(t2);
    i++;
    t2=TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple();
   }
  if (count % 1000000 == 0) {
    outputBag.spill();
    count = 0;
  }
  ;
  count++;
}
if (t2.size()!=0) {
  outputBag.add(t2);
}
}
```